# Match order color and legend in stacked chart with negative values excel

Tags: excel, graph, colors, bar-chart

[Problem]

In a very simple stacked bar graph in excel (example data below), the colors of the positive part of the chart match with the legend (i.e. yellow upper and grey lower in both stacked bars and legend). However, for the negative values the legend is inverse to the actual order of the stacked bar (i.e. blue upper and orange lower in the staked bar but the opposite in the legend).

[Unsuccessful tries]

This is regardless of the actual data in the cells (changing the data doesn't change the colors or the order).
I've tried both changing the last parameter of the formula, and changing the order of the legend manually in the menu desing > select data > move up/down. None of them works, since it changes both the order of the stacked bars and the legends at the same time, so the order keeps unmatched.

[Question]

My question is, how can I match the order of the colors of the staked bars and the legend also for the negative part of the chart?

[image]

Example data:

```
1   -5
2   -1
3   1
4   5
```